# CodeIgniter Phil Sturgeon's template library error

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, module, themes

I'm using a template library from Phil Sturgeon.
I also use modules.

Module blog only works when I add

```
$this->template->set_theme('nvc');
$this->template->set_layout('theme');
```

But I don't want that, I want to set that in the core file. How should I fix this?

Module welcome works perfectly

```
class Welcome extends NVC_Controller {

function index()
{
    $this->template->build('theme');
}
}
```

But module blog gives an error (template):

> Unable to load the requested file: default.php

```
class Blog extends NVC_Controller {

var $num = 10;

function __construct()
{
    $this->load->model('blog_model', 'blog');
}

function index()
{
    $data["result"] = $this->blog->get_all_posts($this->num);
    $this->template->build('blog', $data);
}

}
```

core/NVC_Controller.php

```
class NVC_Controller extends MX_Controller {
function __construct(){ 
    if(nvc_site_open()){                
        $this->template->set_theme('nvc');
        $this->template->set_layout('theme');
    } else {
        show_error("De site is momenteel gesloten.");
    }
}
}
```

What is going wrong? Setting the config layout to "theme" also doesn't work.
The template is stored in `application/themes/nvc/views/layouts/theme.php`.

Answer (score 0):

A file in your CI installation is trying to call default.php which doesn't exist in the given location. Can you please investigate which file it is and post that code here?